# What are some Internal Standards used for Ion Chromatography?

Tags: chromatography

What are some internal standards (ISTDs) used for ion chromatography (IC)? 
For experienced IC users, what ISTDs have you used for your sample analysis?

Comment: This might be related: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14085/4945

Comment: Thank you Martin for your kind advice! I gotta edit the question. :)